# How do I use MAMP to display html/php and GWT code?

Tags: java, gwt, mamp

I have website files running on my local server using MAMP. The project was previously developed using gwt. I have installed gwt and ant. 
Where do I put now my html/php files to be able to compile the java files and, in the same time, to display my html/php files on my local server?

Thanks!,
Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

You mixed several things here, I'll try to make it simple:

1. GWT code is written in java, but eventually it compiles to javascript, so the actual code you deploy is javascript.
2. HTML/PHP/javascript/css files should be put under MAMP/htdocs
3. If you have the source code of the GWT application and you want to view/edit it, you can do it in a regular notepad, but i strongly recommend using an IDE (Integrated Development Editor) like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).

Comment: I am really a newbie to gwt and i am not sure I undrrstood. My files are already on mamp/htdocs  So i can edit my java files on my editor(textmate) and that's it? I don t need to launch gwt?

Comment: No, you need to compile it with GWT compiler which turns the files into javascript and then you deploy the javascript. I'd suggest you take a look at the getting started tutorial: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted